# Input validation - what is wrong with this query?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I try to create validation in APEX.
So in Page Designer I go to "Processing=>Validations". I create new and select "SQL Expression"
Then I type SQL:

```
SELECT article_no FROM dade_dict_articles WHERE article_no = :P11_ARTICLE_NO
```

But I get error:

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 30: ORA-00936: missing expression
```

I try SQL without variable, just:

```
SELECT article_no FROM dade_dict_articles WHERE article_no = 456785
```

Same error.
I try this SQL in SQL Developer - of course it works. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's wrong? The fact that what you wrote isn't a SQL expression - it is a *statement*. Validation is works in a *binary* mode: true or false. If that "something" you use as validation returns TRUE, everything is fine and value entered into an item is OK. Vice versa - if it returns FALSE, the value isn't correct.

I'd suggest you try a *PL/SQL function body that returns Boolean*. For example:

```
declare
  l_article_no   date.dict_articles.article_no%type;
begin
  select article_no 
    into l_article_no
    from  dade_dict_articles 
    where article_no = :P11_ARTICLE_NO;

  return true;
exception
  when no_data_found then
    return false;
end;
```

I guess that this is what you meant to say by this validation. If not, try to adjust it. If you can't, explain what you wanted to do and someone will assist.

Comment: Thank you - meanwhile I solved this doing exactly what u suggest (I just asked myself "how this apex script will know if query returns true or false?"). Just a note that Oracle instruction is misleading - it gives the example of SQL: "SELECT 1 FROM customers 
WHERE last_name = :P1_LAST_NAME" https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/HTMDB/bldr_validate.htm#HTMDB04018 I do not see any other option to put this query (query from tutorial) - SQL is SQL. Oracle should take responsibility for this tutorial.